# I am trying to copy entire directories from one Linux machine to another, including permissions

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to copy entire directories from one Linux machine to another, including permissions, and including the called directory. For example, 
from the parent directory of the destination, I tried 
rsync -rul root@mail3.domain.com/usr/sites/4my.com
but that does not work.
On the calling machine the destination is /home/sites
What should that command be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try `rsync -a username@remote_host:/home/username/dir1 place_to_sync_on_local_machine`

Comment: Might want to add the `-u` flag if you want that behavior (not the default with `-a`)

Comment: Is there a way to script that for a hundred directories, without it asking for the remote site password?

Comment: Yes, using a ssh key.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sudo cp -rp /home/source /tmp/dest`

Comment: That does not work.
I used, from the destination
sudo cp -rp hel@mail3.domain.com/usr/sites/4my.com /home/sites